# iOS Simulator Doesn't Launch on Build. OSX Lion or Xcode 4.1?

Tags: iphone, xcode, osx-lion, ios-simulator

By Doesn't Launch I mean the icon shows up, but its hidden and if I show the windows I can see the iPhone outline but its blank inside.

I can relaunch the simulatore (Out of xcode) and it runs and I see the icons.

When I use Xcode I see: Build Succeeded. Running *project* on iPhone Simulator, but it never sends it over to the simulator.

Background: 
OSX Lion, Xcode 4.1 (from App Store), Error happens on any project.

Comment: I have not (yet) seen that issue on Lion/Xcode 4.1, but I nevertheless can confirm that this bundle (Lion/Xcode4.1) is pretty fragile and tends to get confused especially when it comes to launching apps in the simulator; like "attaching to process.." forever, failed to launch, etc pp. In my cases it always helped to restart Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I didn't just restart Xcode, I reinstalled it and it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by reinstalling Xcode.
 First I ran this command:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
```

Then I deleted the Developer Folder and Reinstalled Xcode. I lost older SDK's but Xcode 4.1 doesn't appear to support them for the simulator anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by deleting the files:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist.lockfile
```

than I relaunch iPhone simulator.